# How to use select in Mysql to expand existing table

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table 1 (4 rows and 3 columns) which is already in a database, I want to expand to table 2 using table 1 and variables (A, B, C, D). Table 2 will contain 8 rows and 5 columns. Can a simple select statement do that?

Table1

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R11 | R12 | R13 |
| R21 | R22 | R23 |
| R31 | R32 | R33 |
| R41 | R42 | R43 |

Table 2

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R11 | R12 | R13 | A | B |
| R21 | R22 | R23 | A | B |
| R31 | R32 | R33 | A | B |
| R41 | R42 | R43 | A | B |
| R11 | R12 | R13 | C | D |
| R21 | R22 | R23 | C | D |
| R31 | R32 | R33 | C | D |
| R41 | R42 | R43 | C | D |

Comment: Your terminology is so off that I cannot understand what you are asking for and I can't figure out how you get to your desired outcome. And what does the table with columns A and B have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 'A' col4, 'B' col5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 'D'
    ) additional_table
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/o13iC_Cr

Answer (score 1):

You could use this DDL and SQL to create Table 2 from Table 1:

```
-- Create Table 2
CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    Column1 VARCHAR(50),
    Column2 VARCHAR(50),
    Column3 VARCHAR(50),
    Column4 VARCHAR(50),
    Column5 VARCHAR(50)
);

-- Insert data into Table 2
INSERT INTO Table2 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
SELECT
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    'A' AS Column4,  -- Add constant value 'A' to Column 4
    'B' AS Column5   -- Add constant value 'B' to Column 5
FROM Table1;

-- Insert data with 'C' and 'D' values into Table 2
INSERT INTO Table2 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
SELECT
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    'C' AS Column4,  -- Add constant value 'C' to Column 4
    'D' AS Column5   -- Add constant value 'D' to Column 5
FROM Table1;
```

If you only want to expand Table 1 to look like your Table 2, you can use this DDL and SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ADD Column4 VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'A',
ADD Column5 VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'B';

-- Update values in Column4 and Column5 in Table1 to match Table2
UPDATE Table1
SET Column4 = 'A', Column5 = 'B';

-- Insert additional rows into Table1 to match Table2
INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
SELECT
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    'C' AS Column4,
    'D' AS Column5
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just clarified my problem